# How much DC voltage is needed to brake a 3 triphasic motor?

Tags: motor, transformer, induction-motor, bridge-rectifier

[image]

What would the nominal parameters of the bridge rectifier and the transformer be?

Comment: Consider the motor's max rated current and the DC resistances involved.

Comment: To figure out what DC voltage and current you need to know the size of the motor, it's moment of inertia, and the load inertia. Most injection braking architectures simply rectify the input line voltage and that could be half wave, full wave or 3 phase.

Comment: Translate the kinetic energy to heat.  The electronic load energy * thermal resistance to max temp rise for the load dump.

Answer (score 2):

The DC voltage will depend on the DC resistance of the motor windings. You need the DC current to be in the range of equal to the rated current of the motor up to perhaps 400% of the rated motor current. The expected braking torque will be something like the curves below.

[image]

Here is a set of curves from another source.

[image]