# Is this a ac three phase motor with a dynamic braking control?

Tags: motor, ac, control

[image]

I am an electrical apprentice and this question popped up on my exam, and then again on an exam  under a different topic, and I have to review it.

**What type of motor control is this?**

*note: I received enough answers to the question above. Thank you.*

**My other question is with regard to the role of the varistor.**

Is it to vary the stopping time? If someone would please guide me in the right path, I would be most obliged.

Answer (score 2):

That is a DC "braking" or "DC injection" braking circuit. Such a circuit is often called a dynamic braking or DC dynamic braking, but I think it is preferable just to call it DC braking. That avoids confusion with another type of braking that is called dynamic braking.

The circuit includes a variable resistor that is used to set the DC current applied to the motor windings. The braking current controls the braking torque. See: [How much DC voltage is needed to brake a 3 triphasic motor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272974/how-much-dc-voltage-is-needed-to-brake-a-3-triphasic-motor) There is also a timer to limit the time that braking current is applied. Applying braking too long can overheat the motor.

Comment: thanks buddy  i did answer this in the exam and could see half a point but the only thing i must have gotten wrong is the role of the varistor i thought it was to vary the stopping time which was one of the answers i could give it must be the wrong answer

Comment: A varistor is a surge suppressor. I think the rectangle & arrow symbol is a variable resistor. See addition to my answer. Adjusting the torque will adjust the braking time, but the braking torque varies with speed, so the braking torque is difficult to estimate.

Comment: yea sorry it is of course only a variable resistor in that circuit thanks for clarifying this what gets me the only other option i could assign to the role of that variable resistor were vary starting time, voltage, or current but my impression was it has got nothing to do with those and it was not supposed to be the control the stopping time option (which i picked), does that mean i been marked wrong? or the context of the question is asked wrong? it is a bloody online format my tech moved to administer exams so i am preparing myself for the proposed resit for that section of that exam.

Comment: The resistor most directly adjusts the current. Current determines torque and torque determines stopping time. However motor characteristics also determine current and torque. Load characteristics also determine stopping time. With all of those related parameters, that is not a very good question. I would be inclined to select torque if it is an option. If torque is not an option, I would pick current. If neither of those is listed, I would say the question is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes DC injection is one of several methods for dynamic braking.

https://circuitglobe.com/induction-motor-braking.html

Comment: Cool but is this motor control circuit one of them?

Comment: Yes and similar to example in my link as the rectified AC is switched between 2 phases after power down