# How does DC braking stop an AC motor without considering current direction?

Tags: motor, dc, induction-motor, emf, braking

When a motor is coasting to standstill, if I apply a DC voltage across the windings I will brake that motor... We'll at least that's what I've read.

Now here's the thing.  With reverse current braking I literally reverse the direction of the motor until it's at 0rpm,and then I disconnect the supply. Which is understandable. But when it comes to DC braking,  I just apply the voltage across a winding,  without taking current direction into consideration, and the rotor will stop. 
How does this happen? In fact, why does it stop to begin with?

Comment: One clue: DC braking is a technique applied to *AC motors.*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_injection_braking.  AC motors expect the current to be changing sinusoidally at a fixed frequency.  It doesn't take much imagination to deduce what would happen if you apply a steady DC current to such a motor.

Answer (score 2):

Induction motor DC injection braking is like eddy-current braking. DC injection braking is accomplished by disconnecting the AC supply and applying a DC voltage to the stator windings. DC current in the stator windings produces a stationary magnetic field. The motion of the rotor bars through the stationary field produces currents in the rotor that have a resulting magnetic field that opposes the motion that produces it. That is best explained in the Wikipedia [eddy current article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current) and the Wikipedia [eddy current brake article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake).

The torque produced by DC injection braking is moderate to high at high speed, increases to a peak at a lower speed then drops to zero at zero speed. DC injection braking will not hold the rotor stationary. It provides only minimal resistance to slow rotation.

See also: [How much DC voltage is needed to brake a 3 triphasic motor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272974/how-much-dc-voltage-is-needed-to-brake-a-3-triphasic-motor)